# Javascript selectedIndex is returning undefined on a HTML drop-down menu

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, selectedindex

Currently I am trying to write a method that appends the value of a dropdown menu to an html link.  However I an having trouble retrieving the text of the selection from the menu.  I narrowed the problem down to the selectedIndex method in Javascript.  It returns undefined.  I've included my method below.

```
function getSize(productID){
    var sizeBox = document.getElementsByName(productID);
    alert(document.getElementsByName(productID).selectedIndex);
    var sizeSelected = sizeBox.options[sizeBox.selectedIndex].text;
    alert(sizeSelected);
    var link = document.getElementById(productID).getAttribute("href");
    link = link + "&size=" + sizeSelected;
    document.getElementById(productID).setAttribute("href",link);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: why not put sample code somewhere like jsfiddle, and yet it is hard to read/understand formatting, do not hesitate about spacing and anything which adds to code more readability)

Comment: So what do the alerts show?

Comment: Thanks everyone!  Problem solved!  I was having problems with the parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getElementsByName` returns an [HTMLCollection](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-75708506). You should say: `getElementsByName[0]`

Comment: Thanks!  I tried the following adjustments: `var sizeBox = document.getElementsByName(productID)[0];` and `var sizeSelected = sizeBox.options[sizeBox.selectedIndex].text;`.  Both still return undefined.